# Tcl/expect regex to implement sed kind of task?

Tags: regex, sed, expect

This is what ia m doing using sed but i need to do it using tcl or expect regex

```
  sed -n '/VLAN Name/,/VLAN Type/p' | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/\n/g' | sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/,$//g'
```

printing lines between two words VLAN Name and VLAN Type
converting spaces into newlines
deleting blank lines

how do i achieve it using tcl or expect.

or can i do

```
set val [eval exec "sed -n '/VLAN Name/,/VLAN Type/p' | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/\n/g' | sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/,$//g'" ] < expect_out(buffer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```tcl
set p false
set vals {}
foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) \n] {
    if {[string match {*VLAN Type*} $line]} {
        set p false
    }
    if {$p} {
        foreach word [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line] {
            lappend vals [string trimright $word ,]
        }
    }
    if {[string match {*VLAN Name*} $line]} {
        set p true
    }
}

puts $vals
```

Comment: Looks like the right sort of thing, though a perfect answer would have some explanatory text (or comments) as well.